# How to disable ion-slide in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to disable `ion-slide` when the slide is completed. That means when we slide the last `ion-slide` and it won't slide back in ionic.

Answer (score 0):

There's an `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` to help you disable the slides manually.
For your case if the user is on the last slide, then you can create a condition wherein if it's the last slide then disable the `ion-slide` directive manually.

See [Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/)